# HBase data loss? Missing HDFS append support? running the HMaster without HDFS append support enabled?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using HBase. I have installed and have the distributed environment running now. 
However, it shows a warning in HMaster's interface page:

"You are currently running the HMaster without HDFS append support enabled. This may result in data loss"
How can I solve this? If I don't use CDH3's hadoop? Can someone give me very detailed instructions please?

[image]

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just found out you cannot (should not) use the standard Apache release of Hadoop 0.20.* with HBase as it is missing append support, HDFS-200. There is no official ASF Hadoop release that has append support. Cloudera's release is the easiest way, can you elaborate on why you cannot use it? It is distributed with the same license as Apache, and if you use a tarball release it is similar to the Apache release and you don't need special permission to install RPMs.

The other choices that I am aware of are rolling your own hadoop from the [hadoop-append branch](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-append/) (not fun) and using MapR, which I have no first hand experience with.

For a while on the HBase mail lists some people have had luck replacing the hadoop jar in their hadoop install with the hadoop jar that gets distributed with HBase. That way does seem fraught with risk and not everyone is happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this kind of data lose very serious??

Comment: The problem is that when you lose data you don't know what was lost.  If you don't care very much about your data, then it is not that important.  But, if it makes a difference to you if you are missing a row or one column from a row, then it is very important.

Comment: What David says. What happens is your writes are no longer durable - if a node (or even regionserver process) dies there is a good chance that recent writes that your application thought were successful will be lost as the regionserver processes have no real way of ensuring all writes made it to disk.